# Is there a simpler way to compare cards where one suite trumps another?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'd like to made a new poker game invent by myself.

In which I need to compare the value of the poker cards.

In this game, Spade>Heart>Club>Diamond(Relation passable, ex:Spade>Club,Heart>Diaomd), with a special rule that Diamond trumps Spade(but still weaker than Heart and Club).

I'd like to use S,H,C,D as head rather than a,b,c,d.

So far there are two players need to compare their card, if their card have same head, then the one with greater number value(represent A to K) wins.

But for me, I've only figure out a clumsy way to realize this comparison. That's to exhaust the possibility.

Like:

If A's card is S, what to do if B's card is S,H,C,D

If A's card is H, what to do if B's card is S,H,C,D

If A's card is C, what to do if B's card is S,H,C,D

If A's card is D, what to do if B's card is S,H,C,D

Thus I need to do almost 16 times of comparison. Though I've figured out that I can do the same comparison with all equal colors like S vs S, D vs D, still I need to do 13 times of comparison.

Is there a better way to do this comparison, or this is already the best way?

Comment: I don't understand how the suits can have cyclic order. What if there are 4 players, and they each have 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 of random suits with no flushes.  They all show 10 high, but every suit is trumped by another.  Do they break the tie with a game of rock, paper, scissors, lizard, Spock?

Comment: @This is only a corner of my game. I'll upload it's English version later. Basically.PlayerA，B,and C both have some cards, they need to put one card on the desktop each round, it's initially back up. After all have put their cards on the desk, everyone turns their cards around and compare with each other. If A won B, B won C, and C won A, they both will do something to the loser, like force others to abandon several cards in their hand. The last one who have cards on his hand will be the winner.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method using a [lookup table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) with *two* dimensions. It can be used, with minimal conditionals, to resolve this ordering between two different suites *because* it considers both suites in the range.

That is, consider a matrix where the columns represent one card, and the rows another

```
   S H C D
S  0 w w l
H  l 0 w w
C  l l 0 w
D  w l l 0
```

where the values are w = win, l = lose, 0 = tie.

Then it is possible to look at the value for a particular row and column to determine which card wins. For instance

```
m(row, col) -> result
m(S, D)     -> l (spade loses to diamond; means diamond wins spade)
m(S, H)     -> w (spade wins heart)
m(H, D)     -> w (heart wins diamond)
m(D, S)     -> w (diamond wins spade)
m(D, D)     -> 0 (huh? well, diamond ties diamond)
```

This can be trivially implemented with lists/arrays, by turning S,H,C,D into the indices 0,1,2,3. It requires only a single look-up (two if you count one for each dimension) to determine the outcome between two suites.

Since the result is one of 3 distinct values, only 2 comparisons (max) will be required:

```
if m(p1,p2) = w : p1 wins
if m(p1,p2) = l : p2 wins - also can be written as m(p2,p1) = w
else            : tie     - it must be that m(p1,p2) = m(p2,p1) = 0
```

Furthermore, by simply replacing w -> (+1) and l -> (-1), a result suitable for a [sort] ordering function is obtained.

Implementing the above should be a practical - and hopefully non-tedious - exercise.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you need to do 16 comparisons.

Let's see if I got this straight:
Assuming there are just two players as you indicated above AND a and b are equal in numeric value...
Let's see...You could write your control statements in this order:

- Suits are identical, it's a TIE.
- A is a spade, B is a diamond, A LOSES.
- A is a spade, A WINS

  - first and second if statements are false
- A is a diamond AND B is a spade, A WINS, else A LOSES.

  - diamonds lose to non-spades
- A is a heart AND B is a club OR A is a heart AND B is a diamond, A WINS.
- A is a club AND B is a diamond, A WINS.

  - only way a club wins
- Else, A LOSES.

  - hearts lose to spades
  - clubs lose to hearts and spades
  - diamonds were covered in covered in the 4th if/else condition.

Is that it?
Am I forgetting any others?

Comment: Since (or *assuming*) there is at most one card of a particular rank/suite, you could continue with the initial logic (there is no need to start adding AND/OR into the mix): "A is a spade, B is a diamond, A LOSES .. A is a spade, A WINS .. A is a heart, A WINS .."

Answer (score 1):

Why not use score(weight) to mark those?

The idea is assign score for each type of card and calculate them for comparison.

Eg.

Assume cards from [3,4,5,...,J,Q,K,A,2] from small to big.

Then you can assign score for it, like [1,10,100,1000...].

And Spade>Heart>Club>Diamond, assign score for it too, like Spade is 4, Heart is 3, Club is 2, Diamond is 1.

So when you get two cards:

Spade 3 and Diamond 4, you get score 1+4=5 for Spade 3 and 10+1 = 11 for Diamond4, therefor Diamond 4 > Spade 3.

Or

Spade 3 and Club 3, you get 5 for Spade 3 and 1+2 = 3 for Club 4, therefor Spade 3 > Club 3.

Comment: Hmm, on further reflection I don't think this will work. The problem is that a Diamond *beats* a Spade, but *loses* to everything else. While a Spade *beats* everything but a Diamond.

Comment: For example, 3 cards, say of the same face value so they all have base score of 0 (to make the math easier). So they are `S(4)`, `H(3)`, `D(1)`. So `S(4)>H(3)` (which is correct), but `S(4)>D(1)` (which is incorrect, as D trumps S). Now, if Diamonds are re-weighted to `D(5)` so that `D(5)>S(4)` it will also mean `D(5)>H(3)`, which is still incorrect.

Comment: @user2864740 Yes, I missed the special rule, single score here will make mistake.